# Execute crontab every first of month and every sunday

Tags: linux, cron

I want to execute a crontab every first of month and every sunday, Here is what I think to do, I am not sure if it will execute it the first of month only if it's a sunday or every first of month and every sunday, Any ideas to clarify this are welcome:)

```
00 16 1 * 7 "command"
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: This is explained in [the manual](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/crontab.5.html), see the "Note:" at the end of the Description section.

Answer (score 0):

You are correct, Kahina.

```
00 16 1 * 7 "command"
```

will run the "command" at 16:00 on the 1st of each month, plus every Sunday.